# Make GitHub action fail when output from find-exec shows error

Tags: bash, github-actions, protoc

I have a GitHub action that includes a call to `find` where the result is chained to another command:

```
echo "Compiling..." && find $GEN_PROTO_DIR -type f -name "*.proto" -exec protoc \
  --go_out=$GEN_OUT_DIR --go_opt=module=github.com/xefino \
  --go-grpc_out=$GEN_OUT_DIR --go-grpc_opt=module=github.com/xefino \
  --grpc-gateway_out=$GEN_OUT_DIR --grpc-gateway_opt logtostderr=true \
  --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative --grpc-gateway_opt generate_unbound_methods=true \{} \;
```

This command works but, if `protoc` fails the action will still succeed and the message will be logged. Instead I want the message to be logged and the action to fail. How can I modify this code to achieve that behavior?

Comment: `-exec cmd ...` would run for multiple times. what final result do you want  if some commands succeed and some fail?

Comment: @pynexj If it fails once the action should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using this [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)'s `-exec` syntax with a trailing `;`:

```bash
-exec command ;
```

which doesn't propagate the exit status from the `-exec` part.

I believe you're looking for this syntax with a trailing `+`:

```bash
-exec command {} +
```

which propagates the exit status.

According to its description from the [find manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> ```
>    -exec command {} +
>           ...
>           If any invocation with the `+' form returns a non-zero
>           value as exit status, then find returns a non-zero exit
>           status.
>           ...
> ```

---